Getting a blue screen error (BSOD) while updating Windows—any ideas on how to troubleshoot this?
Windows update issue
I installed Windows 11 on my laptop using a bootable USB created via the Windows website. However, after every Windows update, my laptop slows down significantly. It takes 2–3 minutes to start up and shut down, and I often encounter a blue screen error during use. To avoid these problems, I either have to pause updates immediately after installing Windows or reinstall the operating system if updates are applied
System information
information
Error
Error Screen

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

the issue is related to windows update whenever windows updtaes are installed my pc becomes slow and blue screen error appear if i do not update the windows or pause them then it works fine

how to fix this issue
